# Why do I get an "Access violation reading location" error with this code?

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why I get "Access violation reading location " with this code example? And how can i fix this?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct StructTest;
struct Struct1;
typedef struct Struct1{
    StructTest* test;
} Struct1;

typedef struct StructTest{
    vector<Struct1*> test123;
} StructTest;

static StructTest* abc;

int test(){
    abc = (StructTest*) malloc(sizeof(StructTest));;
    Struct1* a1 = (Struct1*) malloc(sizeof(Struct1));
    a1->test = abc;
    abc->test123.push_back(a1);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a well asked question ([sscce](http://sscce.org))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's crashing on this line:

```
abc->test123.push_back(a1);
```

The reason is because you allocate it two lines above using `malloc`. Therefore, the contents of `test123` are uninitialized. So it crashes when you call `push_back` on it.

Comment: Thank for your rapid reply, then how can i fix this ?

Comment: Use `new StructTest` instead of `malloc(sizeof(StructTest))`. Same applies to the other `malloc` use `new` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't create `test123`. Allocate the structs with `new` rather than `malloc` and this will create `test123` for you.

```
abc = new StructTest;
Struct1* a1 = new Struct1;
```

Remember to dispose with `delete` rather than `free`.

In fact, since you are using C++ you should simply stop using `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use malloc, use new.  malloc does not cause constructors be called so in this case your vector is not a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

Because, when you allocate a block with "malloc" it may contain garbage, zeros, or whatever.

The object `test123` is a C++ object, whose constructor has not been executed. Try using operator `new` instead.

Also, while we're on the subject, in C++, there is no need to `typedef` structs, they will become first-class names automatically.